# Как убрать все стили псевдокласса с объекта с помощью js или css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, вёрстка

Как убрать все стили псевдокласса с объекта с помощью js или css. Допустим, есть `<div class="block"></div>` и `.block:hover {background-color: red; width: 100%;}`
Как отменть все эти стили псевдокласса для мобильных устройств?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи обычный медиа выражений. Можно просто спрятать, задав `display: none;`, а можно назначит нужные стили.

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.block:first-child {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .block:first-child {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Я спрашивал не про псевдоэлементы, а псевдоклассы. Для них этот способ тоже работает?

Comment: @EasyTactic работает одинаково

Comment: Спасибо, а как сделать так, чтобы ничего не менялось, а просто оставалось как есть?

Comment: @EasyTactic Всмысле ничего не менялось? Уберите display: none;

Comment: то есть, наводишь на объект, и с ним просто ничего не происходит, убрать все изменения, вызванные добавлением hover